# Formula for air density given temperature, pressure, humidity

Tags: atmospheric-science, density, air

What is a good formula for air density (kg/m^3) given temperature (°C), pressure (hPa), and relative humidity?

I tried implementing [the formulas from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_air#Humid_air) as follows:

```
import math
def air_density(temperature, pressure, humidity):
    psat = 6.1078*math.pow(10,7.5*temperature/(temperature+237.3))
    pv = humidity*psat
    pd = pressure-pv
    density = (pd*0.0289652 + pv*0.018016)/(8.31446*(273.15+temperature))
    return density

# Test:
temperature = 15 # Celsius
pressure = 1013 # hPa
humidity = 1.0 # relative humidity [0-1]
density = air_density(temperature, pressure, humidity)
print(f"At {temperature}°C, {pressure}hPa, and {humidity:.0%} humidity, the air density is {density:.3f} kg/m^3")
```

But this gives density (at sea-level STP and 100% humidity) of 0.012, which isn't remotely close; correct value is over 1 kg/m^3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Pa, not hPa for pressure. This gives you a factor of 100 which takes you to the right answer.